# Is there a way to "unlink" duplicated embedded objects from each other in Affintiy Designer?

Tags: affinity-designer, embed

I have created a phone mockup, and placed it into my file. I now want multiple duplicates of my mockup in my file, but change them up a little. Is there a way to duplicated this embedded file without all duplicates referring to the same embedded file?

I cannot unembed it because I use it to replace the screen of the mockup.

I cannot place it again because I made changes to the mockup for it to better fit in the context of my file.

How can I duplicate it without it pointing to the same "embedded file"?